# What is the typical Pythonic view on re-using python modules outside of their initial intent?

Tags: unit-testing, python

**Short Question**
Does it fly in the face of the Pythonic view to reuse / repurpose python modules for projects out side of their intent?

**Background**
Over the past several months I have been working on a project that uses the Python unittest module to run manual system tests.  Please see questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152428/can-python-unittest-automatically-reattempt-a-failed-testcase-suite) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880508/running-subset-of-auto-discovered-python-unittests) and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834872/which-is-the-better-way-to-pass-data-into-python-unittest-redirected-stdin-or-pic) for greater detail on my project and some of the hurdles I have had to overcome.

I would like to know, in general, if it acceptable to reuse modules for other purposes?  Most of the comments I have received have been along the lines of "this is not a unittest", or "you should write your own testrunner".  My push back on that, is if a module does 90% of what you need it to do with litte to no modification and contains additional (knowingly unneeded) functionality why on earth would you write your own module?

Comment: Isn't it always good to use code outside it's original intent (provided it serves the function you want) in any language? I think it's sort of a fact of life that a module designer can never know all the uses their code might be put to.

Comment: What kind of "manual system tests?"

Comment: @cdhowie: Specifically running system tests on an embedded system.  Each testcase actually calls a set of tests that sets power supplies, reads values back from oscilloscopes, dmms, etc...  My linked questions go into more detail on the system under test

Comment: I think I agree with Owen on both counts.  UNIX is still popular today, but most of its users aren't filing patent applications for AT&T.  That said, it is possible to stretch software too far, if it isn't properly enhanced to deal with changing needs.

Comment: @Matthew F: What defines stretching software too far?  The main issues I have ran into have all been based around convenience, meaning the core works great with no modification, changes are to make a user's life a bit easier.

Comment: Mainly when you bolt on changes to cope with a single additional use case, without considering the broader usability.  Imagine AT&T had added code to also file trademark applications, but gave no thought to other more general uses.

Answer (score 4):

Using the code for more than what the original authors intended is usually a good sign, in that the code provides useful tools.  As far as re-purposing modules "outside of their intent" is concerned, well... this is obviously subjective and depends to what extent.

Using [raw I/O functions in `imaplib`](http://docs.python.org/library/imaplib.html#imaplib.IMAP4.read) to implement some unrelated socket-based communication protocol could be considered bad style (to say the least).  However, using the same `imaplib` library to implement some private variant of the IMAP protocol (unlikely to be the intended use) would be IMHO less of a problem.

It's totally understandable that you would find some convenient classes and methods in the `unittest` module to implement other types of tests.  However, the problem is often one of code readability.  *To most Python developers, seeing the `unittest` module closely to the idiomatic recommended usage probably conveys the meaning of **"this piece of code is a unit test"**.*  In terms of "self-documenting code", this is a total failure in the sens that it is [misleading for other developers](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/DELETE-No,-INSERT!-No,-SELECT!-.aspx).

Ideally, this would be a non-question.  The solution would be to refactor the `unittest` module so that code not specific to unit tests is moved to a `test` module or `testbase` module or some such thing.  However, you might find a lot of resistance in such an effort, for political and practical reasons.  It is, after all, a standard library module and can't be modified as easily as your own project.

> Does it fly in the face of the Pythonic view to reuse / repurpose python modules for projects out side of their intent?

In general, I don't think this is "anti-Pythonic", although I think the fact that these comments have occured several times should mean something.

Maybe you can write some sort of `systemtest` module that imports the re-usable stuff from the `unittest` module.  It's a temporary solution that gives both code clarity *and* allows you to re-use the code directly.  Then, you can write a long comment in the `systemtest` module about how all the workarounds are actually better than writing your own test runner.